# Serious CPU Scaling screw up that I need help solving ( underclocked and cant go back)

Tags: cpu, cpufreq, governor

I've been searching this everywhere and I couldn't solve it yet so im praying (almost literally) that some1 can fix this.

I wanted to underclock my laptop for more Battery life, so I searched and after some steps that I dont remember, I changed ( for curiosity and see performance) to 400Mhz (*i5-6200U* lowest capability).

The thing is it became unbearable to use it, and now I can't turn back.

I have already inserted `"intel_pstate=disable"` on kernel so I could use the clock i wanted, however it only fixes it for the first 30seconds after turning on.

The cpufreq-info says that im on 2Ghz for example but if I use "`sudo i7z`", it shows the real clock, 400Mhz.

Does anyone know how I can at least control CPU clock with userspace governor ?

(The command " `sudo cpufreq-set -f "XX"` " doesn't do anything, it "works", but in reality doesnt do anything.

Thanks ahead !

Comment: lowering your CPU frequencies can economize a little power, but it's not really efficient; you won't gain 1 hour with that, it just lower the power needed by fans to cool your CPU

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having a similar issue, check your fans.
One of my fans is not properly working and since it cant work, the CPU throttles at 400Mhz. 
To fix this issue all I had to do was the following commands:

> sudo modprobe msr; 
>   sudo wrmsr 0x1FC 2

This makes the CPU stop throttling and goes back to normal CPU frequencies.